# Fatal error on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, heroku

Im getting  a fatal error in my Ruby and Rails Command Line when I try to

```
bundle install --without production
```

for Heroku.

I'm following the instructions here: http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/create_and_deploy_a_rails_app

This step is in 7.2. Everything was working fine until this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this is failing?

It says something along the lines of 'group' no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)

Thanks

Edit: Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.4'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: Could you actually show the error?

Comment: @BroiSatse slipped my mind, my apologies. Included now.

Comment: Still not seeing any error message or backtrace. BTW, why you are not using official heroku documentation for this? TBH, I don't remember me running `bundle install --without production` at any point with heroku.

Comment: @BroiSatse Trying to get my feet wet in web dev via: http://www.theodinproject.com/web-development-101/installations?ref=lnav. Was just following the instructions for the installfest segment. Everything ran smoothly until now

Comment: @Zack, looks like a problem with your Gemfile. `group` is a method used to provide environment-specific gemsets, but it requires a block. Could you post your Gemfile?

Comment: @ZachKemp Gemfile added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Gemfile`, change

```
gem group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

to

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```